# Why isn't content disposition working in my Azure SAS token?

Tags: php, azure, token

For some reason, I can't seem to set the content disposition of my token without receiving a "Signature did not match" error.

See the code below: The `$rscd` variable works if I set it as an empty string but does not work when I set it as "file; attachment", [as mentioned in the docs.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/service-sas-examples)

Any ideas?

```
$start = (new \DateTime())->setTimezone(new \DateTimeZone('GMT'))->modify('-1 minutes');     
$end = (new \DateTime())->setTimezone(new \DateTimeZone('GMT'))->modify('+10 minutes');
$start = $start->format('Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z');
$end = $end->format('Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z');
$rscd = "file; attachment";
//$rscd = "";

$spr = (getenv('APP_ENV') == 'production') ? "https" : "http,https";

$toSign = $storageAccount . "\n";
$toSign .= "rwdlac" . "\n";
$toSign .= "b" . "\n";
$toSign .= "sco" . "\n";
$toSign .= $start . "\n";
$toSign .= $end . "\n"; 
$toSign .= $rscd . "\n";
$toSign .= $spr . "\n";
$toSign .= "2017-04-17" . "\n";

$signature = rawurlencode(base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha256', $toSign, base64_decode($sasKeyValue), TRUE))); 
$token = "?sv=2017-04-17&ss=b&srt=sco&sp=rwdlac&se=" . $end . "&st=" . $start . "&rscd=" . $rscd . "&spr=" . $spr . "&sig=" . $signature;

return $token;
```

Comment: You're mixing `Service SAS` and `Account SAS`. Please create a Service SAS using this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/constructing-a-service-sas.

Answer (score 0):

As @Gauralv pointed out, you should create a Service SAS with following format:

```
StringToSign = signedpermissions + "\n" +  
               signedstart + "\n" +  
               signedexpiry + "\n" +  
               canonicalizedresource + "\n" +  
               signedidentifier + "\n" +  
               signedIP + "\n" +  
               signedProtocol + "\n" +  
               signedversion + "\n" +  
               rscc + "\n" +  
               rscd + "\n" +  
               rsce + "\n" +  
               rscl + "\n" +  
               rsct
```

And please change your code as below:

```
$start = (new \DateTime())->setTimezone(new \DateTimeZone('GMT'))->modify('-1 minutes');     
$end = (new \DateTime())->setTimezone(new \DateTimeZone('GMT'))->modify('+10 minutes');
$start = $start->format('Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z');
$end = $end->format('Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z');
$rscd = "file; attachment";


$toSign = "rwdl" . "\n";
$toSign .= $start . "\n";
$toSign .= $end . "\n";
$toSign .= "/blob" ."/".$accountName . "/" . $container . "/" . $blob . "\n";
$toSign .= "\n";
$toSign .= "\n"; 
$toSign .= "\n";
$toSign .= "2017-04-17" . "\n";
$toSign .= "\n";
$toSign .= $rscd . "\n";
$toSign .= "\n";
$toSign .= "\n"; 

$signature = rawurlencode(base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha256', $toSign, base64_decode($sasKeyValue), TRUE))); 
$token = "?st=" . $start . "&se=" . $end . "&sr=b&sp=rwdl&sv=2017-04-17&rscd=" . $rscd . "&sig=" . $signature;

return $token;
```